# How to select the first property with unknown name and first item from array in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I actually have two questions, both are probably simple, but for some odd reason I cant figure it out... I've worked with JSON 100s of times before too! but here is the JSON in question:

```
{"69256":{
   "streaminfo":{
     "stream_ID":"1025",
     "sourceowner_ID":"2",
     "sourceowner_avatar":"http:\/\/content.nozzlmedia.com\/images\/sourceowner_avatar2.jpg",
     "sourceownertype_ID":"1",
     "stream_name":"Twitter",
     "streamtype":"Social media"
     "appsarray":[]
   },
   "item":{
      "headline":"Charboy",
      "main_image":"http:\/\/content.nozzlmedia.com\/images\/author_avatar173212.jpg",
      "summary":"ate a tomato and avocado for dinner...",
      "nozzl_captured":"2010-05-12 23:02:12",
      "geoarray":[{
         "state":"OR",
         "county":"Multnomah",
         "city":"Portland",
         "neighborhood":"Downtown",
         "zip":"97205",
         "street":"462 SW 11th Ave",
         "latitude":"45.5219",
         "longitude":"-122.682"
       }],
       "full_content":"ate a tomato and avocado for dinner tonight. 
                      such tasty foods. just enjoyable.",
       "body_text":"ate a tomato and avocado for dinner tonight. 
                      such tasty foods. just enjoyable.",
       "author_name":"Charboy",
       "author_avatar":"http:\/\/content.nozzlmedia.com\/images\/author_avatar173212.jpg",
       "fulltext_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/charboy\/statuses\/13889868936",
       "leftovers":{
           "twitter_id":"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:13889868936",
           "date":"2010-05-13T02:59:59Z",
           "location":"iPhone: 45.521866,-122.682262"
       },
       "wordarray":{
          "0":"ate",
          "1":"tomato",
          "2":"avocado",
          "3":"dinner",
          "4":"tonight",
          "5":"tasty",
          "6":"foods",
          "7":"just",
          "8":"enjoyable",
          "9":"Charboy",
          "11":"Twitter",
          "13":"state:OR",
          "14":"county:Multnomah, OR",
          "15":"city:Portland, OR",
          "16":"neighborhood:Downtown",
          "17":"zip:97205"
      }
   }
 }
}
```

**Question 1:**
How do I loop through each item (69256) when the number is random? e.g. item 1 is `123`, item2 is `646`? Like, for example, a *normal* JSON feed would have something like:

`{'item':{'blah':'lorem'},'item':{'blah':'ipsum'}}`

the JS would be like `console.log(item.blah)` to return `lorem` then `ipsum` in a loop

How do I do it when i dont know the first item of the object?

**Question 2:** 
How do I select items from the `geoarray` object? I tried:
`json.test.item.geoarray.latitude`

and

`json.test.item.geoarray['latitude']`

Comment: for the record, cleaner code and less horizontal scrolling makes it easier for the people trying to help you...

Comment: Sorry, I just copy and pasted it from the feed. Thanks, ill do better next time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Question 1: How do I loop through each item (69256) when the number is random?

You can get property names of a JS object using the [`for in`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) statement:

```
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        alert(property + '=' + object[property]);
    }
}
```

To get the first one of the JSON, you could do:

```
var data;
for (var property in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        data = json[property];
        break;
    }
}
```

---

> Question 2: How do I select items from the geoarray object?

The `geoarray` is actually an array with one item. Use `[0]` to grab it.

```
var latitude = data.item.geoarray[0].latitude;
```

If it in real contains multiple items, then you'll need to loop over it using a simple [`for`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) statement with an index or using [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

---

To learn more about JSON, you may find [this tutorial](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29) useful.

Comment: worked great thanks. And no, the feed is kind of... icky. It only has 1 item in the array. Wish it were cleaner like Flickr, Twitter, etc :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the (somewhat lesser known) `for...in` loop:

```
for (id in feed) {
    if (feed.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        // do something with feed[id]
    }
}
```

The hasOwnProperty check is just for safety, in case something's done weird things to Object.prototype. You might not need it.

As the name says, the geoarray is indeed an array, which contains multiple items. Use `.geoarray[0].latitude` to access the first item, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The order of JSON properties is undefined, so there is no first item.  Some implementations retain the order in which they are defined, but it not something you can count on.